# Does JXTA supports voice chat?

Tags: java, network-programming, p2p, lan, jxta

I'm developing a LAN messenger in java. I'm following P2P approach using JXTA for sending message. Now I want to add extra functionality of audio chat. My main problem is that does JXTA supports sending of voice data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution for this in JXTA. But you can use a BidirectionalPipe (which should be using UDP) for the communication. Check [this](http://www.win.tue.nl/~ymazuryk/books/m_jxta.pdf) book.

Comment: I lead the release of JXTA 2.6 and 2.7. And no, there is no solution out of the box. You have to build it on top of JXTA.